# React removing an element when onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to remove a div when onClick is pressed.  The div exists on my parent component where I have

```
 render() {
    const listPlayers = players.map(player => (
      <Counter
        key={player.id}
        player={player}
        name={player.name}
        sortableGroupDecorator={this.sortableGroupDecorator}
        decrementCountTotal={this.decrementCountTotal}
        incrementCountTotal={this.incrementCountTotal}
        removePlayer={this.removePlayer}
        handleClick={player}
      />
    ));

    return (
      <ContainLeft style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ProjectTitle>Score Keeper</ProjectTitle>
        <Copy>
          A sortable list of players that with adjustable scores.  Warning, don't go negative!
        </Copy>
        <div>
          <Stats totalScore={this.state.totalScore} players={players} />
          {listPlayers}
        </div>
      </ContainLeft>
    );
  }
```

It passes props to the child component where the button to delete the div, here

```
    return (
      <div
        style={{ display: this.state.displayInfo }}
        className="group-list"
        ref={sortableGroupDecorator}
        id="cell"
      >
        <CountCell style={{ background: this.state.color }}>
          <Row style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: '-42px' }}>
            <Col>
              <DeleteButton onClick={removePlayer}>
                <Icon name="delete" className="delete-adjust fa-minus-circle" />
              </DeleteButton>
            </Col>
```

*(I snipped the rest of the code because it was long and not useful here)*

The array (a separate file) is imported into the Parent component and it reads like this

```
const players = [
  {
    name: 'Jabba',
    score: 10,
    id: 11
  },
  {
    name: 'Han',
    score: 10,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Rey',
    score: 30,
    id: 10
  }
];

export default players;
```

So what I'm trying to do is write a function on the main parent that when it is clicked inside the child, the div is removed, deleted, gone (whatever the best term is) sort of like "remove player, add player"

On my parent component, I've written a function where the console.log works when it is clicked in the child, but whatever I write in the function doesn't seem to want to work.

The function I'm building (in progress, I'm still a little lost here) is:

```
  removePlayer() {
    console.log('this was removed');
    players.splice(2, 0, 'Luke', 'Vader');
  }
```

which is mapped over here as a prop

```
const listPlayers = players.map(player => (
  <Counter
    key={player.id}
    player={player}
    name={player.name}
    sortableGroupDecorator={this.sortableGroupDecorator}
    decrementCountTotal={this.decrementCountTotal}
    incrementCountTotal={this.incrementCountTotal}
    removePlayer={this.removePlayer}
    handleClick={player}
  />
));
```

And passed into the child here:

```
render() {
const {
  name,
  sortableGroupDecorator,
  decrementCountTotal,
  incrementCountTotal,
  removePlayer
} = this.props;

return (
  <div
    style={{ display: this.state.displayInfo }}
    className="group-list"
    ref={sortableGroupDecorator}
    id="cell"
  >
    <CountCell style={{ background: this.state.color }}>
      <Row style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: '-42px' }}>
        <Col>
          <DeleteButton onClick={removePlayer}>
            <Icon name="delete" className="delete-adjust fa-minus-circle" />
          </DeleteButton>
```

I know all this is lengthy and I wanted to provide as much detail as I could because React is still new to me and I get confused with some of the verbiages.  Thanks for helping out in advance

Comment: You might want to consider putting the players into the state, since the component won't rerender if you just change an out-of-scope variable.

Comment: so on the parent component I'd put `this.state = {players: players};`?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Don't put it in the render function though! Use either a lifecycle function like `componentWillMount` or put it in the constructor. Then in your render function always refer to `this.state.players`.

Then in your removePlayer() function, copy the array from the state, mutate it (splice your player or whatever) and then call `this.setState()` with the mutated copy.

Comment: ok I understand the broad gist of things here, some things I'm not completely well versed on, but this is the first time I've understood how to do this (I've been plugging away for weeks at this).

Comment: Great. Good luck. hmu if you need some help.

Comment: thanks, go ahead and expect the _hmu_ part because I'm still rather green on this.  That said, I can't thank you enough for taking the time to answer my very confusing question.  I'm anxious to start the opposite which is to add someone into the array as this removing someone has had me tied up for a while (I'm a uiux guy learning js with an emphasis on react for my job)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148695/discussion-between-sthig-and-cynigo).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We sorted it out in chat. Like expected, it was a problem with the state.

I made a small semi-pseudo snippet with comments as explanation:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Your player constant, outside the scope of any React component
// This pretty much just lives in your browser as a plain object.
const players = [
  {
    name: 'Jabba',
    score: 10,
    id: 11
  },
  {
    name: 'Han',
    score: 10,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Rey',
    score: 30,
    id: 10
  }
];

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      players, // ES6 Syntax, same as players: players
      // Add all your other stuff here
    };
  }

  removePlayer(id) {
    const newState = this.state;
    const index = newState.players.findIndex(a => a.id === id);

    if (index === -1) return;
    newState.players.splice(index, 1);

    this.setState(newState); // This will update the state and trigger a rerender of the components
  }

  render() {

   const listPlayers = this.state.players.map(player => { // Note the this.state, this is important for React to see changes in the data and thus rerender the Component
      <Counter
        ..

        removePlayer={this.removePlayer.bind(this)} //bind this to stay in the context of the parent component
      />
    });

    return (
      <div>
        {listPlayers}
      </div>
    );
  }
}





//////////////////////////////////////// Child component

....

<DeleteButton onClick={() => this.props.removePlayer(this.props.player.id)}>

....
```

Comment: When click remove function, it remove  from last element. I can not remove appropriate element.

Comment: @EDISONJ you can also use filter.

Answer (score 3):

Little confused about how the whole app works, but I will try to help you.

To make react changes to the dom, you have to put `players` in the `state`. So, in the `removePlayer` you make a copy of `this.state.players` in a local variable (just to not change the array directly in `state`, it's a good practice), then you make the split in this local variable and finally you `setState({ players: localPlayers})`.

This way the "div" will be removed.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is how i solved this**

i've added an id to the element
and then with function remove i detroyed it

```
const closenotif = () => document.getElementById("notif").remove()
 
<div id="notif">
       <button onClick={destroy}> close </button>
</div>
```

NB : the element is destroyed in the current document
so in the current render

on Next JS this works perfectly

if you are using a live rendering with react this probably won't work

i'll suggest you to work with states in that case